# how to read variable value in java class from jsp

Tags: java, mysql

I have a java class SAMPLE.java and webpage EXAMPLE.jsp. I wish to run java class and read value form jsp. It means user will not run jsp, she will run only java class. find below codes:

```
String mmobile = mobile;
//Prepare Url
URLConnection myURLConnection=null;
URL myURL=null;
BufferedReader reader=null;

String mainUrl="http://localhost:8080/Portal/example.jsp?";
//Prepare parameter string 
StringBuilder sbPostData= new StringBuilder(mainUrl);

sbPostData.append("mobile=").append(mmobile); 

//final string
 mainUrl = sbPostData.toString();
try
{
//prepare connection
myURL = new URL(mainUrl);
myURLConnection = myURL.openConnection();
myURLConnection.connect();

} 
catch (IOException e)
```

I have EXAMPLE.jsp codes given below:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"    
    %>
 <%@ page import="myclass.SAMPLE" %>

  <%
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
  Connection conn = null;
  String mphone = request.getParameter("mobile");

  int mcompregkeyid=0; 
  try {
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/myschema","myuser","mypass");
   Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
 ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("Select max(keyid) from mytable");
 rset.next();
 mcompregkeyid=rset.getInt(1);

 } finally {
if (conn != null) try { conn.close(); } catch (SQLException e) {
    out.println("(\"Could not connect to local server.\nPlease try after some time.!!!\")");
}
 }
SAMPLE.getValue(String.valueOf(mcompregkeyid));

%>
```

Comment: why you write jdbc database connection code inside jsp file ?   
Please comply with the MVC design pattern standard.

Answer (score 0):

why you write jdbc database connection code inside jsp file ?
Please comply with the [MVC](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&client=ubuntu&hs=FHF&channel=fs&ei=6kAJW73YFqmY6ASYhYXACQ&q=java%20mvc%20tutorial&oq=Java%20MVC%20&gs_l=psy-ab.3.1.0l10.851930.853706.0.857830.9.9.0.0.0.0.556.1388.3-1j1j1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..6.3.1384....0.ZwxDd0eO2u0) design pattern standard.